# redirecting to a separate view page

Tags: codeigniter

i have written a login page where both user and admin can login. I want to redirect the user and admin to separate view pages (by checking a field type_id in my 'registration' table).
it correctly get the value of the type_id field but when I want to redirect it depending on the value of type_id it always goes to one page. I don't understand why. please a little help will be great. The part of the code where I get the type_id and try to redirect

```
                    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
{
  $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
  $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
   $data['type_id']=$session_data['type_id'];
  $r=$data['type_id'];

 if ($r==3){
  $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
} else{

$this->load->view('home_view1', $data);
}

 //$this->load->view('home_view1', $data);

}
```

Comment: If this is your code exactly you are missing a =, i.e. `if ($r == 3)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've switched assignment and equality operators.  The line

```
if( $r = 3 ){
```

Should really be

```
if( $r == 3 ){
```